# How to put text between plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a grid of plots using matplotlib, and want text to be between two of the plots. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize = (14,8))
ax[0,0].set_title('(0,0)')
ax[0,1].set_title('(0,1)')
ax[0,2].set_title('(0,2)')
ax[1,0].set_title('(1,0)')
ax[1,1].set_title('(1,1)')
ax[1,2].set_title('(1,2)')
ax[2,0].set_title('(2,0)')
ax[2,1].set_title('(2,1)')
ax[2,2].set_title('(2,2)')
info = 'A = {}'.format(1)
ax[0,1].text(1.2,0.5,info)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which prints this:

[image]

What I want is there to be text between plots (0,1) and (0,2). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [Matplotlibs text.Text classs](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)

You will need to set the x and y values to correspond the middle of the right axes of the plot you want to add the text for and you can use `verticalalignment` and `horizontalalignment` to place the text where you want.

See [some examples here](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html).

Hope this helps.